# Is it possible to (easily) override the defined service in a WSDL spec with PHP's SOAPClient?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I have some legacy PHP code which makes calls to a vendor's SOAP servicein WSDL mode. It's been working fine for years, until this week when the vendor updated their database and changed the URL at which the procedure calls are made.

I worked through the problem from this end in order to diagnose the issue and discovered the URL change - the IP address which the WSDL file is advertising no longer works (all requests time out). I contacted the vendor and got an "Oh yeah, the URL has changed" response.

It seems to me that the simple solution to this is for the vendor to update their WSDL file or configuration so they're advertising the correct endpoint for their service. **Am I correct in assuming this should be a relatively simple configuration change on the vendor's end?**

However... the response I got back from their IT department was that I should simply use this other URL for requests. This is not trivial and will require development time to implement a fix.

Given that I'm probably going to have to fix this on my end, what is the best way to go about it?

1. use `curl` to request the WSDL file, save it locally, amend it, then instantiate the `SoapClient` using the amended version?
2. extend `SoapClient` to tweak the address for each request? (I found a reference to a very old example which can now be found [via the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150423002852/http://www.victorstanciu.ro/php-soapclient-port-bug-workaround/))
3. Something else?

To be clear, I think all of these options suck and the vendor should fix their messed up configuration. But I will probably have to implement a <strike>hack</strike> fix for this.

Comment: Forgive me if I sound woefully ignorant but can you not just simply update the url in your WSDL?

Comment: @Kisaragi the WSDL would be fetched from the third party and cached to disk for subsequent SOAP requests. I mean if this is a PHP application it should be trivial to update? my vote would be option 2.

Comment: The WSDL is not mine; it is fetched from the vendor's server and it is supposed to serve as the specification for the service. The WSDL *should* contain everything needed to make requests against the service. If the vendor is unwilling to update the WSDL, I will have to keep track of the URL in my application.

Comment: Yes you are correct in assuming that it should be a simple fix for the vendor.  But since they are hard coding IP's in a WSDL, and performing migrations without notifying customers, it sounds like you are dealing with amateurs, so your chances of getting them to produce a new WSDL is unlikely.  There might be a systems level solution though, if you can redirect all traffic destined to one IP and have it go to another IP.

Comment: Thanks @KrisPeeling - your suggestion of a network-level fix is interesting. I'm not sure it's better than patching the URL at the application level, but I'll be considering it.